# Count duplicates using count() and count(distinct)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am unclear why this SQL query can be used to count duplicate values for a particular field:

```
select sum(country_count)
from (
select Country, count(Country) as country_count
from Customers
group by Country
having count(Country) > 1
);
```

**returns 88****

while this query cannot:

```
SELECT count(Country) - count(Distinct Country) 
FROM Customers;
```

**returns 70****

As a side note, why do they give different results?

*FYI, these queries work in the W3Schools trySQL interface.

[https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc#:~:text=If%20you%20switch%20to%20a,your%20browser%2C%20for%20testing%20purposes](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc#:%7E:text=If%20you%20switch%20to%20a,your%20browser%2C%20for%20testing%20purposes).

What I have tried:

I have run these queries and they give different results (returning 88 vs 70).  I expected them to produce the same result.

Comment: Why have you tagged both SQL Server and PostgreSQL? What are you really using?

Comment: Stick with one database either SQL Server or Postgres. Remove the other's tag.

Comment: Why do you think those should return the same result? They are doing very different things.

Comment: There may be 1000 records with the same country. `COUNT(COUNTRY)` will include them. You can use `count(Country) - count(Distinct Country) >0` to detect duplicates but not count them.

Comment: As @SeanLange says, these are compeltely different queries. A quick example can demonstrate this: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NyNadjKH).

Comment: Thank you Sean, I would say that I thought I understood both of them.  How about focusing on the second query then.  I would think a count of all the values in a column (i.e. count(Country)) minus all the unique values in a column (i.e. count(distinct Country) would produce the number of duplicate values.  Why is that logic wrong?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "duplicate", @mvoln . Your first attempt counts *all* the duplicate values (if you have 3 instances of a value, it's counted thrice). Your second attempt counts all subsequent duplicate values (if you have 3 instances of a value, it's counted twice).

Comment: Yes that would return the number of values that appear more than once. The top query you have here there is not doing that because in your inner query you are excluding countries that only appear once. As such your result is incorrect.

Comment: Exactly @Thom A!  Thanks for your comment.  I referenced this logic in my comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider these rows in your `Customers` database in `Country` column

1. India
2. India
3. India
4. USA
5. USA
6. Australia

Now consider your 1st query:-

```
select sum(country_count)
from (
select Country, count(Country) as country_count
from Customers
group by Country
having count(Country) > 1
);
```

First let's consider the inner query that you are using:-

```
select Country, count(Country) as country_count
from Customers
group by Country
having count(Country) > 1
```

The output (`Output1`) of this query will be:-

Country | country_count

India   | 3

USA     | 2

Now consider applying the outer query on this output:-

```
select sum(country_count)
FROM Output1
```

The answer should be 5 for this

But for your 2nd query:-

```
SELECT count(Country) - count(Distinct Country) 
FROM Customers;
```

The output should be 6-3 = 3

So, both are doing different things. That's the reason you are getting different outputs.

1st query : Ignore the Countries which have only 1 count and then add up all the counts for the other ones.

2nd query : Ignore the first count from all the distinct Countries and add up rest of the counts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for this illustrative example!  I see now how I was misinterpreting what my second query would do.  In effect, subtracting a count of distinct values from the count of that value will always undercount the number of duplicates (As you remove 1 of the duplicates that exist in the count() query.  Thanks again.  Great response!